# Is there any way to handle blank screen in react JS on production?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have been working on react JS for quite sometime now. It has always bothered me whenever there is a blank screen on production, because of silly issues like props having undefined on the very first render and all.

Just wanted to understand is there a way to fix this? Like if the page goes blank sent the user to home screen or anything like this? Or taking care of all these issues while coding is the only solution?

Comment: search for error boundaries

Comment: You should ***always*** try to defensively code. What you are asking for is basically what unit and integration testing should catch. Things a QA pass should catch.

Comment: @AmanSadhwani looks like it works only with class components and not with functional components?

Comment: @Kiran just wrap your App or another component with this ErrorBoundary. It should look like this ```<ErrorBoundary><App /></ErrorBoundary>```

Comment: In this case, does not matter if App will be a functional or class component

Comment: @DrewReese defensive code i believe will reduce the bugs and issues. But I was wondering there will be edge cases. But I totally agree with your point that it should be a catch from QA. Just wondering as a developer if i can do anything from my side. :)

Comment: You use an ErrorBoundary instance in any component or view that you want to handle uncaught exceptions. Meaning anything within the react tree it renders that throws an error which is not handled by a try/catch block will get caught by the boundary instance and render the fallback instead. You can have multiple boundaries in your application, and indeed you should! That way when something breaks unexpectedly in one area of your app, it doesn't break the entire app.